# Help with Leibnitz’s rule

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

The representation formula for the inhomogeneous wave equation $\square u = f$ has a double integral representing the contribution of the force $f(x,t)$.

$$2u(x,t) = \mathrm{position~and~velocity~terms...} + \int_0^t \int_{x - c(t-s)}^{x + c(t-s)} f(z, s)dz ds$$

Here $z$ is a dummy variable going over the $x$ axis and $s$ keeps track of time from 0 to $t$.

I am wondering how to evaluate $$\partial_x \int_{x - c(t-s)}^{x + c(t-s)} f(z, s)dz.$$ [Leibnitz’s rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) tells how to do this when one of the function variables matches the derivative variable, but in this case $z$ only equals $x$ at one point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, suppose you have a regular integral function $x \mapsto \int_{u(x)}^{v(x)} f(t)\mathrm{d}t$. Suppose $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$. Thus, the above integral function is equal to $F(v(x)) - F(u(x))$. Now, use the chain rule to show that :
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \int_{u(x)}^{v(x)} f(t)\mathrm{d}t &=  \dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(F(v(x)) - F(u(x)) \right) \\
&= F'(v(x))\times v'(x) - F'(u(x))\times u'(x) \\
&= f(v(x))\times v'(x) - f(u(x))\times u'(x)
\end{align}

In your case, this would give :
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\int_{x-c(t-s)}^{x+c(t-s)}f(z,s)\mathrm{d}z &= f(x+c(t-s), s) - f(x-c(t-s),s) 
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks — I was hoping it was like this but wasn’t sure because the usual definition is $\partial_x \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t)dt$, and there is no mismatch between the variable of differentiation and the function argument.

Comment: Yes, here the variable $x$ just appears in the upper and lower bound of the integral, so the calculations are quite easy. It's a little bit harder for an integral of the form $\int_{u(x)}^{v(x)} f(x,t)\mathrm{d}t$. But it is still computable